# Why did my Indoor plants die?

Tags: houseplants, indoors

I had five house plants, one of which was 38 years old. One was a vine which was hardy. I also had two spider plants and a large tree type of plant that has rooted stems. Will look for pictures and add.

My vine was shared with many people because it was such a hardy plant, I had to keep it trimmed because of an indoor only cat.  But the cat could not touch any of the plants because the pots were protected with chicken wire or sitting on top of a metal bar stool (which had lost it's padded seat).

My oldest plant still has three stems but no foliage any more. **My question is why would all but one plant (hanging from ceiling) die off?**  The only difference is the two rats I still have in my home.  I caught a larger one and since then the rats are keeping away from the traps.

I will look for pictures and add.

Comment: What kind of plants? Do you have photographs of them?

Comment: 1. vine which was hardy 2 two spider plants 3. and a large tree type of plant that has rooted stems.  Will look for pictures and add.

Comment: Gotta have pictures.  Cats and rats??  Are you talking about wild rats in your home with a cat?  Cats and rats usually go for protein not plants.  Cats usually dissuade rats from getting into their territory.  And you would have been able to notice long before the animals were a problem.  Please send more information and picture. Take a picture with your phone so we are able to see the plants as they are now?

Comment: 38 year old may have just reached its limit. It happens. A cutting *might* rejuvenate.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I put the information from your comment into the question itself. That way everyone can see it without having to read the comments. I'm going to vote to re-open while we're waiting for pictures. We're a bit different from some other sites. Since you're new here, I invite you to check out the pages of our [help]. If you any questions about how we work, let us know and someone will help you!

Comment: Thank you for editing your question but we still need more details, ideally pictures before they became diseased in order to identify them and if possible whilst they were diseased. If you don't have any pictures of them whilst they are diseased a description of the symptoms might be enough if we manage to identify them.